# Intel HD graphics settings

Tags: intel-graphics, samsung, 14.04

if you got any laptop has an intel cpu in last 3 years in it you have a gpu from intel such as hd graphics 1000 or 5000, there is a program called intel hd graphics settings in windows, can you give me a replacement for that in ubuntu 14.04 lts?? i'm using samsung chronos/ativbook series 7 and can't use my secondary tv properly, i can't see unity and status bar, it's like 1920x1080 cropped into 1600x900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though no one answered, i found a solution by trial and error, if your tv/monitor has screen settings (most of them has) found picture size than select "screen fit".